# IPv4 iptables - known TCP attacks - nowadays irrelevant it seems, please elaborate

Tags: networking, linux-mint, security, iptables

Are the below `iptables` rules made **obsolete by recent kernel versions for example**?

Having zero hits on these for ages, and I do look quite often - before reboots usually.

Our endpoint machines are running: Mint 20.3 kernel 5.4.0-100-generic.

```sh
# Drop known TCP attacks
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags  ALL  NONE                   --jump DROP    --match comment --comment "TCP: NULL scan"
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags  ALL  ALL                    --jump DROP    --match comment --comment "TCP: Xmas scan"
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags  ALL  FIN,URG,PSH            --jump DROP    --match comment --comment "TCP: Stealth scan"
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags  ALL  SYN,RST,ACK,FIN,URG    --jump DROP    --match comment --comment "TCP: Port scan 1"
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags  SYN,FIN  SYN,FIN            --jump DROP    --match comment --comment "TCP: Port scan 2"
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags  FIN,RST  FIN,RST            --jump DROP    --match comment --comment "TCP: Port scan 3"
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags  SYN,RST  SYN,RST            --jump DROP    --match comment --comment "TCP: SYN-RST scan"
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags  ACK,URG  URG                --jump DROP    --match comment --comment "TCP: URG scan"
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags  ALL  SYN,FIN                --jump DROP    --match comment --comment "TCP: SYN-FIN scan"
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags  ALL  URG,PSH,FIN            --jump DROP    --match comment --comment "TCP: Nmap Xmas scan"
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags  ALL  FIN                    --jump DROP    --match comment --comment "TCP: FIN scan"
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --tcp-flags  ALL  URG,PSH,SYN,FIN        --jump DROP    --match comment --comment "TCP: Nmap ID scan"
```

---

I can likely deduce the answer would be "Yes", but as I'm not exactly a *networking guy* I would like to receive a proper answer with some clarification as to why they have no hits. So, I think these rules are maybe only slowing down the OS, not useful at all nowadays? If correct, please say something about what filters them now. Thank you.